# InvalidValueError: Not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral. NaN is not an accepted value

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I am building a component that takes an address and translates it to coordinates using Google Geocode API. From there I am taking the coordinates to show a google map view of the coords. The geocode api is working fine. Within the subscribe block, I am setting the latitude and longitude to variables defined in the class and then calling the mapInitilizer from the within the subscribe block. For some reason, I am getting the error `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value` when I run the code. When I console log the variables before the map init is called, it is showing the correct values but when the function is called, they are returning null.

This is the function that is being called by a button:

```
getLocation() {
  this.http.get<Object>('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=<mykey>')
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.userLat = parseFloat(data['results'][0].geometry.location.lat);
      this.userLong = parseFloat(data['results'][0].geometry.location.lng);
      this.mapInitializer();
    })
}
```

These are the options and marker setting for the map:

```
  coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(this.userLat, this.userLong);

  mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    center: this.coordinates,
    zoom: 8,
  };

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: this.coordinates,
    map: this.map,
  });
```

Once the `mapIntilizer()` is called, it throws that error.

```
mapInitializer() {
  console.log(this.coordinates);
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement,
  this.mapOptions);
  this.marker.setMap(this.map);
 }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't figure out why `userLat` and `userLong` are returning null. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: first of all you mapInitializer() expects two arguments and when  you call it you pass none. 
second I think that your coordinates variable gets initialized when both lat and long are still empty. so by the time the button is pressed and mapInitializer() is called you get that error.

Comment: @MjJameel thanks for the response. The two arguments were actually something I was testing but I’m not actually using it that way. Forgot to take it out for this post. But yes that is the main issue. But I’m not understanding how because In the function, the variables are being reassigned before mapInitializer() is getting called.

Comment: I honestly cant tell for sure because I cant test the code. but why don't you try this bit of debugging. inside of mapInitializer try to console.log(this.mapOptions) and see if the position is correct. 

if it was me writing the code I would probably pass both lat and long into the function and also initialize mapOptions inside mapInitializer() as well.

Comment: @MjJameel thanks;. Tried putting all of the map variables inside the mapInitializer function and passing it from the subscribe block and it seems to work now. I guess it was a scope issue. Thanks again

Comment: No worries. I am glad it worked.